# Scala: getting a map assignment to compile as a specific type rather than Any

Tags: scala

Doing some hackish functional programming, the compiler seems to insist the type produced by this code is `List[Map[String, Any]`.

```
val found = emits map (m => Map("match" -> m("match"), 
                                "indication" -> patterns.find(pattern => pattern._2.exists(fragment => fragment == m("match"))).get._3))
```

I guess this can be easily attributed to the compiler's inability to determine the type of one or more of the values to be assigned to the map's key-value pair; the keys of the map are clearly strings, but somehow the compiler fails to realize the expressions used for the values are also necessarily Strings.

This is cool, but my function needs to return this value `found`. And as long as Scala is type-safe, it's nicer to return a `List[Map[String, String]]` than returning a `List[Map[String, Any]]`. So what's the cleanest most elegant way to get that happening without working the CPU too hard?

Comment: It's impossible to say without knowing the types of `emits` and `patterns`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming find is returning an `Option[String]` you need to add a default case so your value for "indication" should look something like:

```
patterns.find( /*your logic*/) getOrElse "Not Indicated"
```

If find returns `Some(x)` getOrElse will return just the value `x`. If find returns `None` then getOrElse will return `"Not Indicated"`.  As it is right now your map contains a String and an Option[String], the nearest common ancestor of those two is Any.

Also it is bad practice to use `get` on an option as it is not null safe.  Use getOrElse or refactor it another way.

Comment: `get` *is* `null` safe; it can just throw an exception; but no `null`s are involved.

Comment: in other cases, would any of the Scala IDE's help moving faster on this type of issue in any ways?

Comment: In eclipse you can hover over the definition of `found` and it will tell you the inferred type.  Also, you can explicitly declare the type with `val found:List[Map[String,String]] = ...` and the IDE will give you some red check marks and say the type found doesn't match the type inspected.

Comment: @Erik Allik, you are technically correct in that you get a NoSuchElementException, not a NullPointerException but if you are getting exceptions then you aren't using Options correctly.